# How to redirect 301 multi domain site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I like to redirect the following URL: `mydomain.com/myurl` to `mydomain.com/newurl`.

Usually, I could write:

`Redirect 301 /myurl /newurl`

But I need it specifically for `mydomain.com` because I got other domains too which I do not want to redirect.

What is a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Write a rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/\oldurl$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com\/oldurl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com/\newurl$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried the following but it's not working - no redirect.

RewriteEngine On
 
... RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test-domain\.de\/share$ [OR] ...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test-domain\.de\/share$ ...

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/test-domain\.de\/newshare$1"  [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Try this Apache .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^mydomain\.com$"
RewriteRule "^" "http://%1/newurl" [R=301, L]
```

If .htaccess file is placed on root folder and `newurl` is relative to root folder use this code instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^mydomain\.com$"
RewriteRule "^" "newurl" [R=301, L]
```

If your hostname is `www.mydomain.com` change `"^mydomain\.com$"` to `"^www\.mydomain\.com$"`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading here: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/rewritecond-and-rewriterule-tricks-for-htaccess/

I got it working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/oldurl$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/mydomain\.com\/newurl" [R=301,L]
```